# Why do Stackers consistently vote down humorous responses?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, humor

I've noticed that humorous responses tend to get voted down quickly and regularly. Typically software developers have a keen sense of humor, and nurture it as a survival instinct.  It does not make sense to me that Stackoverflow's default group responsive behaviour causes vote downs on humour!

What is the driving force behind the peer pressure to answer seriously and in a straight-forward manner?

Comment: Sorry, Kieveli, but you'll have to go and ask each person who has ever down-voted a humorous post - there's no other way to know.

Comment: From now on, I choose to vote up all humorous posts!!
Fight the power!!

Comment: One person against the combined might of SO - let me know how that works out for you :-).

Comment: Thanks Kieveli.  Mayhaps, we might create a more inclusive software development questions site that up-votes humor.

Comment: I'm not saying up-voting humor is the key - up-voting correct answers is the key... but why down-vote humor? That's the crux.

Comment: The downvote popup states "This was not helpful" - some people may not consider humor helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: I question the sanity of people who mark offensive those posts which are neither hate speech, spam nor abuse.

Comment: Kieveli, check out my bio page - the most up-voted and most down-voted answers are both jokes. Comedy's a brutal game, sometimes you hit and sometimes...

Comment: Hey! Stop up-voting my fart joke! It *deserved* that score... ;-p

Comment: I WILL FIGHT THE POWER!!!

Comment: (without compromising the integrity of the correct answer)

Comment: Humorous responses should be comments to the question.  Not a true "answer"

Comment: You should print out a list of the offenders (the humorless misanthropes), like Jay and Silent Bob did, and fly all over beating them up like they did at the end of the Jay and Silent Bob Strike Back movie. :)

Comment: @Simucal - I agree.

Comment: Hello meta! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: -1 for calling us 'stackers'

Comment: During the first few months of Stack Overflow, humorous responses were consistently **up-voted**. What a difference a year makes.

Comment: It's because we, collectively, are dead inside.

Answer (score 85):

There are plenty of websites you can go to if you want humor - SO is supposed to be about providing useful answers to useful questions.

That's why I also vote down the "What's your favorite data structure"-type questions.

They add little of value to SO - if they were phrased as "What's the best data structure in C++ for representing a phone directory", that would be ideal.

I think the powers that be have basically stated that a small amount of programming-related humor is acceptable but they don't want the site being swamped.

What I tend to do is look at the content of my "answer". If it provides useful information, I make an answer out of it, even if there's a little humor - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602138/is-a-debugger-the-mother-of-all-evil/602205#602205) for example. If it's all humor and not really useful, I'll either put it in as a comment (likely) or just move on (less likely, due to my personality type).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1000 times!

Comment: I liked your answer and I notice people comeup with generic question to get high reps and badges. If you put up meaningless generic question like what is popular, what is worst, etc you lot of people answer and the question gets badges as well as up votes. Total useless questions.

Comment: it would be nice if we had a separate site where we could do this...

Comment: Sounds like someone went to UNC-Chapel Hill's CompSci department for undergrad.

Comment: @paxdiablo So is it fine to add humor in comments?

Answer (score 39):

Because none wants another Slashdot, where you have to dig around about 800 replies down before you get something useful.

Comment: What is this... 'slashdot' of which you speak?

Comment: You could of course ignore tags such as: offtopic, humor, perhaps also polls and subjective.

Comment: AFAIK, only questions are tagged, not answers.  So ignoring tags doesn't help when a good, meaningful question gets 800 content-free joke answers.

Comment: Some of us *do* want another slashdot :-)

Answer (score 22):

Use comments to make Jokes :) I personally like to Joke too, but I can also understand the more serious minded that jokes are out of place in serious answers, unless you use sarcasm to Joke but present the truth, however sarcasm doesn't seem to be recognizable by many folk here... so ...

Right and Funny answers are fine IMHO

Comment: would like to vote up comments tho.  humor has a place, but not in answers

Comment: Agree. If I feel like jesting, I do it in a comment. And not just because it won't get me downvoted. ;)

Answer (score 15):

I've had a couple of "joke" answers voted up - maybe you just aren't as funny as you think you are. :-)

Comment: BWAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!
Nope. I'm funny.

Answer (score 14):

1. Down vote funny responses.
2. ??????????
3. Profit!

Comment: Seems someone does not have a sense of humour :(

Comment: Or hopes to profit from downvoting funny responses.

Answer (score 11):

One of the goals is for this to be a reference in place for years to come.

The jokey answer may be funny today, but will be annoying to the person looking for an answer to that question in six months.

I think downvoting is a good remedy -- the joke responses get a brief moment in the sun, then are out of the way of the helpful answers.

Comment: humor is timeless

Comment: Another reason why upvotes should be cancellable without a time limit.

Answer (score 8):

humor does not compute

Comment: Hahah! ? Syntax Error

Answer (score 7):

If the only point of the post was to crack a joke, make a pun or to prove a certain level of cultural awareness, then it should be voted down.

If an otherwise solid answer was sweetened with a light touch and a whimsical reference, it should be voted up ... but then it would have been voted up anyway, because of its content.

Answer (score 6):

I don't downvote humorous answers, but others do...

[Should wrong but funny answers be posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/should-wrong-but-funny-answers-be-posted/19151#19151)

But, I must admit, it does limit the distractions.

Comment: Humorous answers yes, humorous comments no. Se, that's the difference. I think they are a distraction and as such they are better suited as comments. It's also easier to follow.

Answer (score 5):

Mayhaps, an additional **funny** tag to the voting scheme...

### **+1** votes: This was helpful and funny.

### **+1** votes:  This was helpful.

### **0** votes:  This was not helpful, but funny.

### **-1** votes: This was not helpful.

Comment: And before you know it we have 20 buttons to choose from, just like the famous windows shutdown menu. Nope, we should keep it simple.

Comment: I like it, but it should be in the FAQ and not clutter the voting arrows.

Comment: +1 for the use of 'Mayhaps'. One of my favourite all-time non-words.

Comment: How about "Funny","Informative","Insightful","Flamebait" and "FILE_NOT_FOUND"? Of course, each combination should have a button of its own ;)

Comment: what about those of us who **like** having 20 buttons on the Windows shutdown menu??

Comment: quack quixote: Well, I for one like the 6 different buttons *on the shutdown menu* - because it's a menu I don't use too often; but when I do, I need one of the 6 options, each time I may need a different one, and it's no big hassle to spend 20 seconds once a day to choose the right one. On the other hand, I can't foresee 6 options on something I'm supposed to use very often - 20 seconds x 30 votes per day, that comes to ten minutes of time, just for casting votes. To me, that's unacceptable for an action that's supposed to be *simple* - in addition to the other activities here.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the driving force behind the Stackoverflow's peer pressure to answer seriously and in a straight-forward manner?

"This is a place for questions that can be answered!" << [This](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

*[Iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iff)* you answer the question that was asked, and answer it correctly and specifically, *then* it's time for other features, e.g. humor.

*Else*, it's not really a good answer, therefore is unhelpful, therefore should be downvoted.

Comments, apparently, do not have these requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we should ask for a humor tag to mark answers, so those that don't want humor can filter them out, and those that like humor can enjoy themselves. After all Humor is the highest (requires most knowledge and empathy) form of human communication ;)

Comment: You're clearly a DB Administrator right? - yeah thought so

Answer (score 2):

I brought my sense of humor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245334/cant-activate-rake-000#245340), but no one laughed.

Comment: I did. FIGHT THE POWER!!! Up-voted!

Comment: That was quite funny, bring on some sense of humour i say

Comment: Upvoted. :) ...

Comment: I did :) Very funny.

Answer (score 2):

Humorous responses tend to get voted down quickly and regularly... if humor (or at least attempted humor) is the primary point of the response.  This is as it should be, because humor does not help to resolve technical issues nor to answer most questions of the sort that SO is intended to deal with.

If, OTOH, the reponse is a solid, meaningful, and helpful answer to the question which just happens to have some humor mixed in with the solid, meaningful, and helpful information, then I've seen no tendency for such to be downvoted.

The problem is merely that useful content and humorous content tend to be inversely proportional.  SO doesn't downvote humor, it downvotes non-helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If an attempt at humor within an answer is otherwise not valuable, and if the question is otherwise serious, and if the answer is distracting, then I think downvoting is justified.

These sorts of "humorous" answers are akin to some jack-ass making jokes or throwing pies at someone trying to change a tire. Humor is fine as a complement to getting things done, when it gets in the way of work, then it becomes a problem. Because, to be honest, a lot of this "humor" isn't as funny as the posters think it is.

As someone above pointed out, valuing humor as highly as concrete help is a recipe for a rapidly diminishing signal to noise ratio, as seen on slashdot and elsewhere.

**If you want to make a joke in a serious topic, put it in a comment.**

If the entire Q&A thread is humorous, then downvoting isn't justified (unless the joke isn't funny, live by the sword, etc.)

Edit: keep in mind this is coming from someone who posted a funny answer to the (now deleted) "How to make a peanut butter and jelly sandwich" question. Humor is good, but you have to be careful from letting it get out of control.

Comment: I am throwing a http://ja0hxv.calico.jp/pai/epivalue.html at you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I've noticed that humorous responses tend to get voted down quickly and regularly.

I have noticed that they are sort of OK as long as the question is in the vague/subjective/social/whats-your-favorite-colour category. [This humorous but useless answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139228/what-do-you-do-with-a-developer-that-does-not-test-his-code#139412) is currently at +3.

So, IMHO it depends on the question. Humorous answers to precise technical questions are annoying; to vague questions, they might not be.

Answer (score -1):

May be the moderators or Whoever wrote the FAQ should be more clear when thy say " Bring your sense of humour, But not when a serious question is asked"..or something like that..

Answer (score -1):

People can downvote, but if there is little downvotable posts, normal but not strictly programming related posts get downvoted easily too. That includes humorous posts but also posts that don't seem to be programming related even if they are at least somewhat.

Comment: -1 Because you told me to.

Comment: @Rich B: I didn't tell you to downvote, I just told how things are.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if what you're saying is exactly true, down votes aren't consistent for humorous responses. In fact the **highest voted answer** on Stack Overflow is funny (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)) as it still answers the question, conveys a message and everyone loves it.

Sometimes people are funny enough to get away without answering the question, and in that case the up votes will generally outweigh the down votes. I generally try to go by what the alt tag says for the image "This answer is not useful", and base my up/down votes around that. If you can reply with a clear answer and add in some humour, everybody wins, but if you have nothing constructive to say add it as a comment.