# Humor in Comments deleted?

Tags: feature-request, humor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do Stackers consistently vote down humorous responses?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17782/why-do-stackers-consistently-vote-down-humorous-responses)

I find that answers and comments are downvoted or flagged simply because of humor or a pop culture reference like "OMG, WTF, or EPIC Fail" - this seems like rabid fanboy behavior, down voting is fine, but allow comments to be down voted instead of deleted, deletion when the comment is in good humor should be allowed.

Comment: OMG! WTF? EPIC FAIL!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's being asked here ...

Comment: Effectively the same as: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17782/why-do-stackers-consistently-vote-down-humorous-responses
...read the responses. Humor can survive, but only if it's funny.

Comment: Delete this imo.

Comment: @Shog9: Humor must be funny? Since when?!

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Comments are automatically deleted once they've been flagged 5 times (more times if the comment has been upvoted). That means at least 5 people DON'T think it's in good humour. S[OFU] are not joke sites. There's room for humour, but the information should come first.

Comment: No? No what? No jokes?

Comment: OK, OK, I got one. So Linus, Steve and Bill walk into a b...ZZZZZTTT! Flagged! Deleted!

Comment: **NO, NO JOKES ALLOWED. BY LAw**. Every time somebody makes a joke, Jeff Atwood makes a backup. That just shows you how many jokes get made.

Comment: I'm here as proof that Phoshi made a joke.

Comment: Damn! Downvote/Flag me for my sins :(

Comment: the # of flags also scales a bit with the # of upvotes a comment has. The more upvotes, the more flags required before auto-deletion. It's more likely a moderator will delete your comment once flagged, as it shows up in the flagged comment report / status.

Comment: Aah, that makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: This comment thread is going to make no sense when Welbog changes his name again. Or when there arise new people who know not the story of the (non-)backups.

Comment: @mmyers: I petition you to change your name to buzzkiller.